# django admin: exclude not working in change_form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following admin class:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class CommandAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','status','get_requester', 'justification')
    readonly_fields = ('name','status','get_requester', 'request', 'justification')
    exclude = ('request',)

    def get_requester(self,obj):
        return obj.request.requester

    get_requester.command_order_field  = 'requester'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_requester.short_description = 'Who Requested'  #Renames column head


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = ['request']
        form = super(CommandAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        print request
        qs = super(CommandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('request')
        return qs.filter(status='pending', request__isnull=False)
```

The Command model looks like this ...

```
class Command(models.Model):
    ... bunch of fields ...
    justification = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    request = models.ForeignKey('sudorequests.Request', blank=True, null=True)
```

When I get to the change form the 'Request' object still appears on the form.  Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: tried to remove `request` from the `readonly_fields` tuple? or/and call `self.exclude = [...` after you call the super class of `CommandAdmin`.

Comment: Oops! I forgot I had put that there. Thanks!